# Wikitude - @synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode

Tags: objective-c, cordova, xcode5, wikitude

I'm using wikitude, xcode5 and phonegap for my mobile app project. I got this error when I try to build the project.

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/rmbp/apps/rmbp/iphone/native/WikitudeSDK/WTARViewController.m:19:1: @synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode
```

Why?

Comment: Because `weak` references are only allowed when you're using ARC, and it appears that you aren't.

Comment: how I can solve that error? can u explain it more details?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Wikitude or PhoneGap, but `weak` references are a feature of ARC, or automatic reference counting (there's never been garbage collection on iOS), and they don't make any sense without it. The simplest solution is just to enable ARC (in the "Build Settings" page of your project settings in Xcode) but I don't know enough about Wikitude or Phonegap to know if that'll mess up something else you're using.

Comment: still not working. Other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which PhoneGap version are you using?
Since PhoneGap version 2.1.0, ARC is enabled by default and you shouldn't have any problems.

You might check your PhoneGap version and update to 2.1.0+ (current release is 3.3).